# Buddypress and Bootstrap, how to enqueue the JS

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, buddypress

[buddypress e-bootstrap](http://buddypress.org/support/topic/buddypress-e-bootstrap)

WP – 3.8.1
BP – 1.9.2
Plugins – BuddyPress

I can´t make the site work in 100% 
Some erros like crop avatar, accept friendship or reject, don´t work very well

I'm building a theme bootstrap for wordpress and buddypress.

Help-me?

Answer (score 1):

The right way to enqueue the Bootstrap JS is like this

```
function my_enqueue_scripts() {

    // register the script
    wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, false );

    // enqueue the script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Ref:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script